# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 PHP/MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sql-server

I am creating a script to automatically export the results of a query i have created in MySQL, in a table format in an email.  I have it working up to the point where i receive 2 emails, one email gives me the error: **SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1 [ SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`,`region`, MONTHNAME(`date`) as`month` FROM tempur_stores.stats WHERE `date` > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 WEEK) AND `date` < DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY `region`, MONTH(`date` ]**  I am sure my syntax is correct as i get the expected results whenever i run my query in SQL itself.

The other email just has the headings i have specified in my code, **count**, **region** and **month**

Any suggestions where i am going wrong/missing something?

PHP

```
public function action_third_party_searches() 

{
    $stmt = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`,`region`, MONTHNAME(`date`) as`month` FROM tempur_stores.stats WHERE `date` > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 WEEK) AND `date` < DATE(NOW()) GROUP BY `region`, MONTH(`date`');
    $result = $stmt;
    $sendTo = 'myemail@live.com';
    try {
        $result = $stmt->execute()->as_array();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        mail('myemail@live.com', 'Tempur 3rd Party Store Locator Searches', $e->getMessage());
    }

    $subject = 'Third Party Store Locator Searches - '.date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-1 week")).' - '.date("Y-m-d");
    if (count($result) > 0) {
        $toEmail = array('
            <html>
            <head>
            <title>Third Party Store Locator Searches</title>
            </head>
            <body>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>Count</td>
                    <td>Region</td>
                    <td>Month</td>
                </tr>
        ');
        foreach ($result as $row) {
            $toEmail[] = '
                <tr>
                    <td>'.$row['count'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['region'].'</td>
                    <td>'.$row['month'].'</td>
                </tr>
            ';
        }
        $toEmail[] = '
                </table>
                </body>
                </html>';
    } else {
        $toEmail = array('No searches were taken last week!');
    }

    $headers = "Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n".
    "X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\n".
    "MIME-Version: 1.0\n".
    "From: T UK <no-reply@me.com>\n".
    "Mailed-by: T UK <no-reply@me.com>\n".
    "Reply-To: T UK <no-reply@me.com>\n".
    "Return-Path: T UK <no-reply@me.com>\n";

    mail($sendTo, $subject, implode('', $toEmail), $headers);
   //   mail('myemail@live.com', $subject, implode('', $toEmail), $headers);

}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're missing a closing parenthesis in your query:

```
$stmt = DB::query(Database::SELECT, 'SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`,`region`, MONTHNAME(`date`) as`month`
                                     FROM tempur_stores.stats
                                     WHERE `date` > DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW()), INTERVAL -1 WEEK)
                                     AND `date` < DATE(NOW())
                                     GROUP BY `region`, MONTH(`date`');
                                                        ----------  ^ right there
```

Comment: I have a ' at the end of my query?

Comment: Sigh... Just put a parenthesis **)** before that apostrophe and it should work.

Comment: Sorry! My bad, i should read more carefully! Thank you it works!

Comment: Hi I know this is an old question but I'm receiving the same problem here is the link to the problem hope you can be of help. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24657044/sql-error-need-advice-on-query